# How to count the (substring) from database using c#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, combobox

I have to count the total number of gender from the db column using substring, where is the last digit is even its female and if its odd its male. so i have to count the total number of male and female. Im having a issue with my code where i cant count the total number using substring in the query. How to use count and substring at the same time?

```
string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["pranklinne"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        SqlDataReader reader2;
        int gen;
        int gen1;
        string sex = "";
        
        string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Person] WHERE SUBSTRING(NRIC, 12, 1)";
       
        //gen = int.Parse(query.Substring(11, 1));
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NRIC", cboGender.SelectedText);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            int.TryParse(query, out gen);

            while (reader.Read())
                {
                
                string temp = reader[0].ToString();
                int.TryParse(temp, out gen);

                    if (gen % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        sex = "Female";
                    
                    cboGender.Items.Add(sex.ToString());
                    }
                    else if (gen % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        sex = "Male";
                    
                    cboGender.Items.Add(sex.ToString());
                    }

                var _items = this.cboGender.Items.Cast<string>().Distinct().ToArray();
                this.cboGender.Items.Clear();
                foreach (var item in _items)
                {
                    this.cboGender.Items.Add(item);
                }

            }
            
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(sqlex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Comment: You are doing count*. That will give you count only It will not give you individual values from rows. What column value you need to select from the database? That you need to write in select. `Select <<columnname>> from [Person]....`

Comment: "SELECT SUBSTRING(NRIC, 12, 1) AS ExtractString FROM [Person]"  How do i use count in this query ?

Comment: It is not clear why you need to use count in the query? Count gives you the number of rows and how that value can help you to decide gender of person.

Comment: If you want total number of rows returned by `SELECT SUBSTRING(NRIC, 12, 1) AS ExtractString FROM [Person]` query then you should use a counter while iterating thru the reader.

Comment: I have already do the function to appear male or female ...but the count is not yet done

Comment: What's the purpose of count?

Comment: To count the total number of male and female....Okay maybe i edit the code

Comment: Now where and how to implement the count ?

Comment: You can get that count in c# code while iterating thru the reader.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
string query = "SELECT NRIC FROM [Person];    
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
int maleCount =0;
int femaleCount =0;
while (reader.Read())
{
    string temp = reader[0].ToString();
    var gen = int.Parse(temp.Substring(12, 1));
                    
    if (gen % 2 == 0)
    {
        femaleCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        maleCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: **var gen = int.Parse(temp.Substring(12, 1));** I have an error with this line

Comment: You have written the same code as I have written? What's the error you are getting?